# Вывод разного контента в зависимости от страницы Yii

Tags: php, yii

Появилась задача: разделить контент в представлении по страницам.

Например:

- Для главной страницы используется первая html разметка под главную.
- Для страницы каталога, с этого же вида используется другая разметка.

Возможно в yii есть какие-то готовые компоненты под это?

Если коротко, то нужно разделить разметку одного представления для показа на разных страницах.

Или подскажите, как лучше это реализовать.

Comment: два разных layout? Об этом речь? Да, у yii можно сделать несколько

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, не совсем, в самом виде нужно произвести эту проверку и разделить разметку

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответы, сделал так:

```
<?php if (Yii::app()->controller->id != 'controllerID' && $this->action->Id != 'actionID' ) { ?>

<div class="">HTML код для одной страницы</div>

<?php } else { ?>

<div class="">HTML код для другой страницы</div>

<?php } ?>
```